# crawledPage.HttpWebResponse is null in Abot

Tags: c#, assemblies, web-crawler, httpwebresponse

I'm trying to make a C# web crawler using [Abot](https://code.google.com/p/abot/)

I followed the [QuickStart Tutorial](https://code.google.com/p/abot/wiki/v1d1QuickStart) but I cannot seem to make it work.

It has an unhandled exception in the method `crawler_ProcessPageCrawlCompleted`, in exactly this line :

```
if (crawledPage.WebException != null || crawledPage.HttpWebResponse.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK) 
{
   Console.WriteLine("Crawl of page failed {0}", crawledPage.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
}
```

Because `crawledPage.HttpWebResponse` is null.

I'm probably missing something but what ?

### Notes and Full Code :

I edited my app.config file as the tutorial suggests, and here is my class (that references Abot.dll) :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


using Abot.Crawler;
using Abot.Poco;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows.Forms; // for HttpStatusCode

namespace WebCrawler
{
    public class MyCrawler
    {
        public MyCrawler()
        {

        }
        public PoliteWebCrawler crawler;
        public void initialize()
        {
            // 3. Create an instance of Abot.Crawler.PoliteWebCrawler
            // 3.2 Will use app.config for confguration
            // because I choose 2.1 === edited app.config
             crawler = new PoliteWebCrawler();

            // 4. Register for events and create processing methods (both synchronous and asynchronous versions available)
            crawler.PageCrawlStartingAsync += crawler_ProcessPageCrawlStarting;
            crawler.PageCrawlCompletedAsync += crawler_ProcessPageCrawlCompleted;
            crawler.PageCrawlDisallowedAsync += crawler_PageCrawlDisallowed;
            crawler.PageLinksCrawlDisallowedAsync += crawler_PageLinksCrawlDisallowed;
            #region(Step 5. Add custom objects to crawl bag ?)
            //5. Add any number of custom objects to the dynamic crawl bag. These objects will be available in the CrawlContext.CrawlBag object.
            // ???
            /*
            PoliteWebCrawler crawler = new PoliteWebCrawler();
            crawler.CrawlBag.MyFoo1 = new Foo();
            crawler.CrawlBag.MyFoo2 = new Foo();
            crawler.PageCrawlStartingAsync += crawler_ProcessPageCrawlStarting;

            void crawler_ProcessPageCrawlStarting(object sender, PageCrawlStartingArgs e)
            {
                    //Get your Foo instances from the CrawlContext object
                    CrawlContext context = e.CrawlContext;
                    context.CrawlBag.MyFoo1.Bar();
                    context.CrawlBag.MyFoo2.Bar();
            }
            */
            #endregion

        }// initialize()

        public void doCrawl()
        {            
            CrawlResult result = crawler.Crawl(new Uri("http://yahoo.com"));

            if (result.ErrorOccurred)
            {
               /* line 60 : */  // Console.WriteLine("Crawl of {0} completed with error: {1}", result.RootUri.AbsoluteUri, result.ErrorMessage);
                // I commented out because it outputs the error : 'Abot.Poco.CrawlResult' does not contain a definition for 'ErrorMessage'
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Crawl of {0} completed without error.", result.RootUri.AbsoluteUri);
            }
        }

        void crawler_ProcessPageCrawlStarting(object sender, PageCrawlStartingArgs e)
        {
            PageToCrawl pageToCrawl = e.PageToCrawl;
            Console.WriteLine("About to crawl link {0} which was found on page {1}", pageToCrawl.Uri.AbsoluteUri, pageToCrawl.ParentUri.AbsoluteUri);
        }

        void crawler_ProcessPageCrawlCompleted(object sender, PageCrawlCompletedArgs e)
        {
            CrawledPage crawledPage = e.CrawledPage;            

            if (crawledPage.HttpWebResponse == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("HttpWebResponse null");
            }

            /* line 84 : */ if (crawledPage.WebException != null || crawledPage.HttpWebResponse.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                Console.WriteLine("Crawl of page failed {0}", crawledPage.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Crawl of page succeeded {0}", crawledPage.Uri.AbsoluteUri);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(crawledPage.RawContent))
                Console.WriteLine("Page had no content {0}", crawledPage.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
        }

        void crawler_PageLinksCrawlDisallowed(object sender, PageLinksCrawlDisallowedArgs e)
        {
            CrawledPage crawledPage = e.CrawledPage;
            Console.WriteLine("Did not crawl the links on page {0} due to {1}", crawledPage.Uri.AbsoluteUri, e.DisallowedReason);
        }

        void crawler_PageCrawlDisallowed(object sender, PageCrawlDisallowedArgs e)
        {
            PageToCrawl pageToCrawl = e.PageToCrawl;
            Console.WriteLine("Did not crawl page {0} due to {1}", pageToCrawl.Uri.AbsoluteUri, e.DisallowedReason);
        }
    }// end of public class MyCrawler
}
```

The error is in line 84.

Also, an additional detail (maybe it indicates what I'm missing) is in line 60, which is :

```
'Abot.Poco.CrawlResult' does not contain a definition for 'ErrorMessage' and no extension method 'ErrorMessage' accepting a first argument of type 'Abot.Poco.CrawlResult' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 0):

It means that you are encountering a url that  is not responding to http requests (ie.. it doesn't exist like http://shhdggdhshshhsjsjj.com). That would likely cause both the HttpWebResponse and WebException properties to both be null.