# Abot Crawler - How to detect null response

Tags: vb.net, web-crawler, getresponsestream

I am using vb.net and have a handful of URLs that refuse to be crawled.  I would really like to detect when a crawl returns a null response, but seem to be having a problem figuring out HOW.

Code:

```
Public Sub crawler_ProcessPageCrawlCompleted(sender As Object, e As PageCrawlCompletedArgs)

    pageNumber += 1
    Try

        Dim crawledPage As CrawledPage = e.CrawledPage


        If (Not (crawledPage.HttpWebResponse Is Nothing) And Not (crawledPage.WebException Is Nothing)) Or crawledPage.HttpWebResponse.StatusCode <> HttpStatusCode.OK Then
            CrawlFailed(e.CrawledPage.ToString, Failed)
        Else

            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(crawledPage.Content.Text) Then
                CrawlFailed(e.CrawledPage.ToString, NoContent)
            Else
                StoreContent(e)
            End If

        End If


    Catch ex As Exception
        RichTextBox1.AppendText(e.CrawledPage.ToString & " - " & ex.Message & vbCrLf)
    End Try

End Sub
```

I put in the Catch-Try to capture that exception, but I would really rather capture it in my CrawlFailed subroutine to *do something* with that URL.

I have tried to figure out how to use GetResponseStream and Stream.Null, but can't seem to figure out how to detect an empty stream :(  I'm just missing something, but I've googled all over the place and the best I can find is this thread:  [crawledPage.HttpWebResponse is null in Abot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21335662/crawledpage-httpwebresponse-is-null-in-abot).

However - that doesn't really explain HOW to detect and code against the result.

Comment: `GetResponseStream and Stream.Null`? Do you mean this issue (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22921555/check-null-for-httpwebresponse)? You don't need to check for Stream.Null and doing so accomplishes nothing. Also, HTTP does not recognize a "null" response but you can detect an empty stream by reading from it or possibly by using the Length property.

Comment: I did read through that, although I just now saw your final analysis on it.  Since I'm using Abot, I'm not quite sure how I detect whatever it is giving me as an output, then?  I'm sure I'm missing something out of your response @usr, maybe you can help me understand?

Comment: I don't know anything about Abot but if `crawledPage.HttpWebResponse` is of type `HttpWebResponse` then my answer applies. Just read from that stream to obtain the content and possibly find it empty. If you can't make that work post the reading code.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue (dotnet core), with a fiddler session I could see the response actually did come. But I also saw it took a long time for the site to return result.

Try setting config.HttpRequestTimeoutInSeconds to a higher value. It resolved my issues.